# Css3 animation jumps to last keyframe on mobile without animating

Tags: javascript, ios, css, animation, mobile

I am trying to build a simple animation of a beaker tipping over. Everything is working great on desktop, but both iOS Safari and chrome, when the animation starts it jumps immediately to the last key frame (100%). So this tells me the animation is firing, but for some reason it just doesn't want to well... animate.

Here is my scss code. I have an auto-prefixer, I've checked and double checked, it doesn't seem to be anything to do with -webkit. Any help would be awesome!!

```
/** Our Process Area Edits **/
&.our-process-title {
  #our-process-svg {
    width: rem-calc(150);
    height: rem-calc(150);
    margin: 50px auto;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    animation-name: beakerShake;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-play-state: paused;

    &.running {
      animation-play-state: running;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes beakerShake {
      0% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
      5% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(20deg); }
      15% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-25deg); }
      20% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
      40% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
      50% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(5deg); }
      55% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-10deg); }
      58% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(15deg); }
      60% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
      65% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
      72% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(30deg); }
      78% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-35deg); }
      85% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
      95% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
      100% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(105deg);}
    }

    @keyframes beakerShake {
      0% { transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
      5% { transform: rotateZ(20deg); }
      15% { transform: rotateZ(-25deg); }
      20% { transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
      40% { transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
      50% { transform: rotateZ(5deg); }
      55% { transform: rotateZ(-10deg); }
      58% { transform: rotateZ(15deg); }
      60% { transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
      65% { transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
      72% { transform: rotateZ(30deg); }
      78% { transform: rotateZ(-35deg); }
      85% { transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
      95% { transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
      100% { transform: rotateZ(105deg);}
    }
```

EDIT:

After trying one last thing, of course I found the culprit. I am drawing this particular svg's path, and then when it's done drawing, changing the animation play state to running. Here is my js :

```
setTimeout(function(){
  svg.style.animationPlayState = svg.style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = 'running';
}, 4500);
```

Once i removed that functionality it all worked fine. I really need this the animation to fire after the svg is drawn (for obvious reasons). Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Actually, i think the repaint due to the SVG not being already draw is making the browser to skip the current animation playing. So you might want to let it render (aka display) the SVG first, then animate it. That's what the setTimeout is doing since it waits a bit, but that's not a "clean" solution anyhow

Comment: What about inserting the css animation property after the SVG is done, instead of just setting it's play state to running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is an issue with how iOS and the mobile broswers handle the animation play state... Essentially they don't.

The solution was to add the class

```
.no-animation {
    animation: none !important;
}
```

to the element, and remove that class with js when the time is right. Feels kind of like a hack, but its the only thing I could find to work on both mobile and desktop. If anyone has better suggestions, I'd love to hear them!

Comment: I now this is a lot of time to remember but if you can attach a resource to your claim about mobile browsers doesn't handle animation play state, it could be very helpful.